# 2sxc - HttpResponseMessage reference missing in Custom api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

When I return base or custom object from `SxcApiController` everything work OK,
but If I try to return:

"`HttpResponseMessage`", Something like:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new {  Message = "ERROR : " + ex.Message } );
```

I get error:

> 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.",

How can I fix this? How to add additional reference to api controller?

I already add : "`using System.Net.Http;`" in api controller but this is not the problem...

== Added =============================

I found this code inside 2sxc.csproj file:

```xml
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

And there is Version=2.0.0.0

Can this be a problem?

== Complete controller =================================

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using DotNetNuke.Data;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
using DotNetNuke.Security;
using ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi;

public class InstallController : SxcApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    //[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Host)]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public object DbTablesCreate()
    {
        var result = new {  P1 = "test1", P2 = "test2" } ;
        try
        {
            // Some code I want to protect...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);
            //return new {  Message = "Returned error with status code OK" };
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        //return new {  Message = "Returned ok with status code OK" };
    }
}
```

Complete result : 500 Internal Server Error

> { "Message": "2sxc Api Controller Finder: Error while selecting /
>   compiling a controller for the request. Pls check the event-log and
>   the code. See the inner exception for more details.",
>   "ExceptionMessage":
>   "c:\websites\dev.lea-d.si\Portals\0\2sxc\nnApp\api\InstallController.cs(23):
>   error CS0012: The type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' is defined
>   in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.", "ExceptionType":
>   "System.Web.HttpCompileException", "StackTrace": " at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledAssembly(String
>   virtualPath) at
>   ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.AppApiControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) in
>   C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\Sxc
>   WebApi\AppApiControllerSelector.cs:line 77" }

============== Solution1 ================

I copy the

*System.Net.Http.dll*

to Bin folder of site and then also add:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
```

Now stuf work

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: If I try to use Request.CreateResponse inside SxcApiController I get error described in question. If I return string, bool or some anonimuos then all work OK, but then is also always status 200 in response, and I like to return NotFound or other statuses with CreateResponse

Comment: Show more of the controller action.

Comment: @Nkosi I added complete controller code and complete error response

Comment: Just realized you got it working by adding the dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy the file:

System.Net.Http.dll

to Bin folder of the site and then also add:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
```

Now stuff work

Answer (score 0):

As the error message stated, you needed to add the requested `dll` to the site. The framework searches the `bin` directory of the site for the necessary references in order to operate correctly.

Also assuming that the controller is derived from `ApiController` you can try the following using a different syntax

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
//[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Host)]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IHttpActionResult DbTablesCreate() {
    var result = new {  P1 = "test1", P2 = "test2" } ;
    try {
        //...code removed for brevity
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);
    }
    return OK(result);
}
```